# How to ng-repeat over a comma seperated string

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array as per below;

```
var myObj = {
    paramA1: "some value",
    paramA2: "a=1, set=2, of=332, comma=21, sep=12, values=01132"
}

$scope.myObj = myObj;
```

I want to display the above in my HTML as:

```
paramA1: some value
paramA2: a=1
         set=2
         of=332
         comma=21
         sep=12
         values=01132
```

However, the issue i am having is that the contents of paramA2 is a string.

So i have tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj track by $index">
            <strong>{{key}}:</strong>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {{value}}
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Which gives me:

```
paramA1: some value
paramA2: a=1, set=2, of=332, comma=21, sep=12, values=01132
```

So i have tried adding a function on a second repeat to conver paramA2 to an array:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj track by $index">
            <strong>{{key}}:</strong>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="myItem in getMyItems(value)">
                    {{value}}
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>

$scope.getMyItems = function(item) {
      var array = item.split(',');
      return array;
};
```

But then how do i ng-repeat over the new array??

Comment: So, all you want to achieve is the unordered list of these values? If so it seems that you should change {{value}} to {{myItem}}

Comment: I agree with @greenshade. I would suggest changing $scope.getMyItems() though, so that it doesn't create a new Array object every single time it gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a filter to represent the "array".

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', 'fooFilter', MyCtrl]);
function fooFilter() {
  return function(input) {

        return input.split(',');
  };
}



<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">
            <strong>{{key}}:</strong>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="paramA2Item in value | foo">
                    {{ paramA2Item }}
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

see the full example in http://jsfiddle.net/s2doyrq4/

hope this helps.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Simply exploding that string before exposing to your view:

```
$scope.iterable = myObj.paramA2.split(', ');
```